# Mysql Beetween compare against one field?

Tags: php, mysql

Hope someone can help me out here...

Im trying to figure out how i can do a check against a Database field.

I have a field called "level" and it stores the data like "0-7" (From 0 to 7)

How can I do a mysql query to check:

Table "values":

```
ID  | LEVEL
1   | 0-7
2   | 3-6
3   | 4-5
```

Query where value "4" is beetween any of the rows "level" .

Thanks for the help!

Otherwise I will have to either first get all the rows and do a split to verify ou create a new field with the low value and a high value and then to the compare.

Update:

All great awnsers, but even worst the idiot that did this table

Created and extra field like:

```
ID  | LEVEL | Name
1   | 1-7   | level
2   | 3-6   | xperience
3   | 4-5   | level
4   | 1-5   | level
```

Meaning that I have to substring according also to where the "Name" = level.
Is it possible?

Comment: It will probably be better if you can change your table design to include something like `low` and `high` columns, and then check against this range. Something tells me it will eventually make your life easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to do it if you do not want to change your schema:

```
create table test(
    id integer primary key auto_increment,
    level varchar(50)
);

insert into test(level) values('0-7');
insert into test(level) values('3-6');
insert into test(level) values('4-5');

commit;

select *
from test
where 4 between SUBSTRING_INDEX(level, '-', 1) AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(level, '-', -1);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make 2 fields called "level_min" and "level_max" and make them store the data from "0" to "7"
Then use mysql BETWEEN query

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE 4 BETWEEN level_min AND level_max
```

most important thing that such a query can use an indedex, id needed.
which is essential for whatever more or less living database.

Comment: Beat me to it, while I was playing with my substring functions in mysql! This is the best way to do it really, as the current table design is awkward.

Answer (score 0):

As noted it would be a good idea for performance to split the field.
If you for any reason can't do it you can use substring_index:

```
SELECT * FROM values WHERE 
substring_index(level,'-',1) <= 4 AND 
substring_index(level,'-',-1) >= 4;
```

Comment: i don't understand your updated problem. Cant you just add "AND `Name` = 'level'" to above query?

Comment: I also  have to check for xperience...

level 5 And experience 2

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table_name where 4 between SUBSTRING_INDEX(LEVEL,'-',1) 
and SUBSTRING_INDEX(LEVEL,'-',-1);
```

Answer (score -1):

I would split the level field into 2 fields, min and max, to make life easier.
But you can do a

```
select Id from table where 4 between SUBSTRING(level, 0, 1) and SUBSTRING(level, 2, 1)
```

on your current data. Mysql should automatically cast the substring to an int.

Comment: I think it wont for for level = '12-15'